# Adding opacity layer to a HTML section with sidebar.js / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using [Sidebar.js](http://makotot.github.io/sidebar/) and would like to add an CSS `opacity` setting to the main container section when the sidebar is revealed. (Similar to [hypebeast.com](http://hypebeast.com) when you click the three bar icon).

I not sure whether to add an overlay `div` and then hide/show it with jQuery or whether a function can be added to the sidebar js to do it (this seems the way to go).

I would like to control the opacity with CSS but if it's in the js then that's fine as well.

Any help welcomed.

My html:

```
<div class="wrapper jsc-sidebar-content jsc-sidebar-pulled">
    <nav>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-bars jsc-sidebar-trigger"></a>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <!--content with opacity on clicking above nav-->           
    </section>
</div>
<nav class="sidebar jsc-sidebar" id="jsi-nav">
    <!-- nav bar content -->
</nav>
```

Side bar js and jquery

```
<script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/sidebar.js"></script>
<script>
        $('#jsi-nav').sidebar({
            trigger: '.jsc-sidebar-trigger',
            scrollbarDisplay: true,
            pullCb: function () { console.log('pull'); },
            pushCb: function () { console.log('push'); }
        });

        $('#api-pull').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#jsi-nav').data('sidebar').push();
        });
        $('#api-push').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#jsi-nav').data('sidebar').pull();
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/79sb2rq9/

add and remove class for wrapper and using pseudo add a overlay

```
.wrapper.overlay {
    position:relative;
}
.wrapper.overlay:before {
    content:'';
    background:black;
    opacity:.5;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: That's great - any thoughts on controlling the delay?